# Downloaded file inside dockerfile missing after build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to dockerize my php application, this is my very first attempt.

Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
WORKDIR /php55
ARG GIT_TOKEN
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# Install apache2
RUN set -x; \
    perl -pe 's/(\S+\.)?archive\.ubuntu\.com/mirror.sg.gs/g' /etc/apt/sources.list > temp-sc && mv temp-sc /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && sed -i 's#security.ubuntu.com#mirror.sg.gs#g' /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install --yes apache2 curl wget nano \
    && a2enmod rewrite headers

# Configure apache2
RUN set -x; \
    sed -i.backup 's#/var/www/html#/var/www#g' "/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf" \
    && echo "ServerName localhost" > "/etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf" && a2enconf fqdn \
    && cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf.backup

# Copy configuration
COPY ujian.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN set -x; \
    curl -H "Authorization: token ${GIT_TOKEN}" -O https://git.mydomain.com/api/v1/repos/liso/ujian/archive/main.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p /var/www/ujian \
    && tar -xvzf main.tar.gz -C /var/www/ujian --strip-components=1 \
    && rm main.tar.gz

# Install PHP
COPY install-php5 .
RUN chmod +x install-php5 && ./install-php5
EXPOSE 80 7825
CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  ujian:
    image: liso/ujian-dockerize
    container_name: docker-ujian
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        GIT_TOKEN: ${GIT_TOKEN} # from .env file
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

.env contain my api token to git instance.

---

The problem is after building, I can't find the downloaded file located in `/var/www` on the container, it's empty.

```bash
root@6835554968db:/var/www# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 30 11:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jan 30 11:11 ..
```

I have rebuild several times but still empty /var/www, I never touch docker before so I'm really lost. Can you help me debugging this problem ?

Comment: It doesn't look like you `COPY` anything into that directory in your Dockerfile; is that part of the setup missing?  It also looks like a `volumes:` block in the Compose file is trying to overwrite the image content with something else; is the left-hand side of that entry correct?  How are you running the `ls` command you show?

Comment: @DavidMaze The idea is so I can modify /var/www files inside docker container by only editing www directory outside. That's what the volumes are for. As for copying, as you can see I was downloading the file using `curl` to directory /var/www.

Comment: @Liso It doesn't work like this. Mounting a volume into a container, overwrites the path within the container. So if `./www` outside of your docker-container is empty, then you overwrite `/var/www` within the container with this empty directory and that's why it is also empty within the docker-container.

Comment: @Tobias Ah I didn't know that, if so how can I edit the files inside ? Do I need to drop to container shell everytime I want to do that ?

Comment: @Liso Instead of placing the files into the `/var/www`-directory within the docker-container by your dockerfile, remove this RUN-comand form the dockerfile and place the files directly in the `/www`-directory outside of your container. Then mount this directory into the container like you already do. Then you can edit the files in `/www` outside of the container and this will also applies the changes to `/var/www` within the container.

Comment: If your apache only makes the plain files of the directory accessible over network without caching or other fancy stuff, then it shouldn't be necessary to restart apache or the container after you changed the files.

Comment: @Tobias I'm trying to automate that process, after looking around, it seems I need to add entrypoint in my dockerfile. Is it doable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it seems the volume was overwriting my previous downloaded files, that's why it keep missing after I launched the container. Ultimately I had to create `docker-entrypoint.sh` script which run **after** the contain has been provisioned. Then all is well.